# Google count instances of values within one column when searching another

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, count

I want to be able to do the following:
- List all words and phrases in Column A
- Create a list of selected words and phrases in Column B
- Count the number of times any word/phrase within Column B occurs within Column A

=COUNTIF(A:A,B:B) does not work
=sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(A2:A, JOIN("|",B2:B)))) does not work

The above only works if only one keyword appears in Column B but sets to 0 if a second is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(A2:A, "*"&filter(B2:B, len(B2:B))&"*"))
```

Comment: Yes! Although it lists each keyword count (which is fine as this is also useful to me)

Comment: If you want to sum all, just wrap the above in sum().